# how to select a particular object class in a bunch of classes in opencv2?

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

i have trained a yolo v3 model for opencv detection. this trained model has 'person', 'tables', 'chairs'. These classes will be detected in `detect_obj`. i want it to perform certain functions when only `person` is detected and certain functions when other objects are detected. how can i do it?

```
detect_obj = self.DetectionObj(detections, depth_frame, netMain)
     
image_rgb = self.cvDrawBoxes(frame_resized_rgb, detect_obj)
        
cv2.imshow('Vision', image_rgb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array of detections searching for the classes that you want to do something;
Maybe this can help you:
[Detect missing objects in a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888569/detect-missing-objects-in-a-video/63888919#63888919)

Comment: if b'person' in detections < 3:
                plug.turn_off()
                print("off")   this is not working

Comment: The 'b' stands for bit, just remove the b and try again. If this not work, you need to see how your detections are saved, just use a debugger or print the detections